# Google Cloud Vision API : OCR text detection giving inaccurate result- Node JS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-vision

I have used the below code to perform text detection on the image.

```
const client = await new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({ credentials });
const [result] = await client.textDetection(path);
console.log(result.textAnnotations);
```

the intended result is **BBTPB9999Q** but
the program output is **BBTPB9999C**

Is there any way to improve the accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the quality of the pictures matters. So I think improving quality of analyzed image is only way to improve results of detection when it comes to descriptions similar to your example, like serial numbers etc. Once I had an idea to try to convert images before, ex. make them monochrome, however I never got test results worth implementing. You may try this...

At the moment, in Google Cloud Vision, only way to improve the the result  for the same picture is to [Specify the language](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#specify_the_language_optional), however this will work only when you want to detect text in already known language.

Comment: @vitooh The quality of the picture is good, when I tried the same image with another library getting the expected result